# CodeIgniter autoloading form validation rules set not working with parameters

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

Following CI user_guide, I have created a configuration file named "form_validation.php" with in it the following sets:

```
$config = array(
'user/create' => array(
    array(
        'field' => 'id', 
        'label' => '', 
        'rules' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'first_name',
        'label' => 'lang:First name', 
        'rules' => 'required|max_length[30]'
    ),...        
),
'user/update' => array(
    array(
        'field' => 'id', 
        'label' => '', 
        'rules' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'first_name',
        'label' => 'lang:First name', 
        'rules' => 'required|max_length[30]'
    ),...
)
);
```

In my 'user' controller, when I call the 'create' method, hence with the URL `http://localhost/my_ci_application/user/create`, the statement `$this->form_validation->run()` automatically runs the first set of rules defined in my configuration file. This is the expected behaviour from what I read in the user guide.

But when I run the following URL `http://localhost/my_ci_application/user/update/1` to update the user whose ID is 1, it does not automatically load the 'user/update' rules set. It seems like because of the parameter, CI expects to find a 'user/update/1' rules set, which of course I cannot create because the ID of my users will vary all the time when calling this method.

Am I understanding this right? If yes, then that's a pity as I thought standard CI URL were formed like: controller/method/parameters... so I would expect the form validation class to only consider the first two URI segments?!

FYI, if I write in my user.update method the following, my validation rules work fine:

```
$this->form_validation->run('user/update')
```

So my question is really if I understood the autoloading of rules properly or not, and if there is anything we can do to autoload those rules even with methods having some parameters.

thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your form_validation.php file:

```php
$CI =& get_instance();

$config = array(
    'user/update/' . $CI->uri->segment(3) => array(
    ....
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understant this question u will need call validation, for example:

```
$this->lang->load('form_validation', 'portuguese'); //if u have order language
if($this->form_validation->run('user/update') == FALSE)
{
//msg error
}
else{
//save
}
```

To get the value for the url dowel u need:

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

i hope this has helped

Comment: Well, yes indeed I know I need for the moment to call the validation rules myself by passing 'user/update' through the run() method. My question is more to know if there is some kind of configuration to be done somewhere so that CI does not take all the URI segments but only the first two AUTOMATICALLY, so that I can continue using '$this->form_validation->run()' without passing anything.

But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the library to achieve this

`application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function run($group = '')
    {
        if($group == '')
        {
            $group = '/' . implode('/', array_slice($this->CI->uri->rsegment_array(), 0, 2));
        }

        return parent::run($group);
    }

}
```